# I need help writing this IF statement in JS

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a game where you enter your score into an input box for each turn you take. I wrote a for loop to add the total of each turn and have it displayed in the "Total Score" box. However in this game, if your "Total Score" at the end of all of your turns is greater than or equal to 50, you get a 10 point bonus.

So I've created another input box called "Total". I want to create an IF statement so that if the "Total Score" input box has a number in it that is greater than or equal to 50, your score plus the 10 point bonus is displayed in the "Total" box beneath it. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
//input form   

Turn 1: <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty">
<br>
Turn 2: <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty">
<br>
Trun 3: <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty">
<br>
<b>Total Score:</b> <input type="text" name="TotalScore" id="TotalScore">
<br>
Bonus (+10): <input type="text" name="bonus">
<br>
<b>Total:</b> <input type="text" name="Total">

//for loop

function findTotal() {
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    var tot = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('Total').value = tot;
}
onblur = "findTotal()"

//my attempt at the IF statement ("alert hello" is just a place holder)

var tots = document.getElementById('TotalScore');

if (tots.value >= 50) {
    alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: your code outside the findTotal function will run once, when the page loads - perhaps you want to move that code inside the function?

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking to see if the user got the bonus at the end of the `findTotal` function (where you anyways just finished calculating the `total score`):

```js
function findTotal() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }

  document.getElementById('TotalScore').value = tot;

  var bonus = tot >= 50 ? 10 : '';
  document.getElementById('bonus').value = bonus;
  document.getElementById('Total').value = tot + bonus;
}
```

```html
Turn 1: <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty">
<br> Turn 2: <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty">
<br> Turn 3: <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty">
<br>
<b>Total Score: </b> <input disabled="true" type="text" name="TotalScore" id="TotalScore">
<br> Bonus: <input disabled="true" type="text" id="bonus">
<br>
<b>Total:</b> <input disabled="true" type="text" id="Total">
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide the textbox id as,

```
<b>Total:</b> <input type="text" id="tots" name="Total">
```

and use if as,

```
 if($('#tots').value>=50){}
```

Comment: I think there is no jQuery in the question code and it also does not include a jQuery tag.

Comment: I need help writing this IF statement in JS, The title of the question, so i did it in javascript. Thanks for your regards.